# how to compress text and image files using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, lob

what mechanisms one can use to compress following ? Since I am using multiple databases I want it to be under the hood like how hibernate handle using Dialects.

```
 @Lob
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
 private String data;
```

or

```
@Lob
private byte[] data;
```

Answer (score 1):

`LOB` which stands for "Large object file" is not neccesary contains text information, so I think mapping it to `String` field, even with the help of `@Type` annotation is not the preferred solution, if your DBMS(es) supports `CLOB` or similar things.

**TL;DR** I think the second piece of code is way better `LOB` mapping.

Comment: clob internally compressed ?

Comment: No, it is not. `CLOB` is `character large object file`, so it is best-used for huge text information. `LOB` is higher-level abstraction.